# Can I do cluster analyses with Hadoop and can I hook Hadoop to MongoDB

Tags: hadoop

I am a newbie to Hadoop, I went through a few blogs and skimmed through a couple of books on a subject. To guide my further studying I need answer to these two questions:

1. How much I can really do with Map-Reduce? From examples I see I can do min(), max(),  sum(), count(). You can probably as easy to do average() and even standard_deviation(), but is that it? What if I want to run a query such that “customers who bought X also bought Y” (sort of join table to itself in SQL terminology). What if I want to do graph analyses or cluster analyses is Haddop’s map-reduce of any help or I am still pretty much on my own?
2. If I have existing database, let's say it is big (1 petabyte) and distributed, let’s say it is MongoDB with clusters, shards and all that. Can I hook Haddop to my existing MondoDB shards, or do I need to copy my data (and respectively keep it synchronized as it changes). The latter, if that is what I really need to do, sounds like expensive process, is there anything in Hadoop to help me do it.
   Detailed elaborative answer or a link to such will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. MapReduce is pretty general structure for computation and while it is not appropriate for every situation, it is flexible in being used for a wide variety of problems. For examples of what you have described, you can refer to Mahout: http://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/clusteringyourdata.html
2. Using the mongodb connector you can directly access a mongo database as a mapreduce inputformat without having to sync the data to HDFS: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop

Alternatively mongo itself allows you to write queries in mapreduce to be directly executed by the database. I'd recommend aggregating the data as much as possible in this way before interfacing with hadoop/hdfs to reduce the potential amount of data transferred between the two systems.